# How to place div below the image in the div container using flex?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

What is the simplest way to place div above the image in the div container using flex box?

The expected result is shown in the image example.

That is the starter code:

```
 <div className={"main"}>
    Корзина
    <div>
        <div className={"num"}>1</div>
        <image/>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: I am expecting this result where the number 1 is under the red circle:]

Answer (score 1):

Put the container `position: relative` and the image `position: absolute` and then use flexbox for alignment.

```css
.parent-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.container img{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  Корзина
  <div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/50/50" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @OksanaB Glad to help. If it helps you can accept it as the "Accepted Answer" if you want.

Answer (score 0):

We can provide background on the upper div and place other content inside the inner div. The position properly handles those things here, so we can have inner div content on top of the upper div.

```css
#background{
 display: flex;
 background-image: url("https://e1.pxfuel.com/desktop-wallpaper/908/281/desktop-wallpaper-non-copyrighted-no-copyright.jpg");
 position:relative;
}
#content{
 font-size:40px;
 color:red;
 padding:20px;
 margin:100px auto 100px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="background">
    <div id="content">
        Your content goes here
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```